# Drupal 7 Gmap module - javascript error "Javascript is required to view this map."

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drupal-7, required

I am using GMap module in Drupal 7. I have generated the macro code, pasted into contact page, added macro filtering to Filtered HTML  text format.
 It has worked correctly for about 3-4 hours and then suddenly stopped displaying google map. Instead of map I see the message "Javascript is required to view this map.".
Google maps is displayed correctly on Gmap configuration page. It does not display on the page where I added it as macro. All necessary js files seem to be loaded. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created API key for rendering Google map? This error usually occurs because of incorrect API key.
Try to edit the existing one or create a new API browser key in https://code.google.com/apis/console/

```
sitename.com 
sitename.com/* 
www.sitename.com 
www.sitename.com/* 
*.sitename.com 
*.sitename.com/*
```

Hope this helps..